# How do I remove first two dots from string using regular expression?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have string `A.B.C No.example/23` and I want to remove the first two occurrences of dots, but keep the third dot alone.
The output should look like this:

```
ABC No. example/23
```

What regex can I use to achieve this task of removing the first dots?

Answer (score 5):

You can search using this regex:

```
^([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.(.*)$
```

And replace by:

```
$1$2$3
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO9jV1/2)

For you example input it will give:

```
ABC No. example/23
```